# Summing functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to approximate a function using a haar wavelets in matlab. While trying to approximate for f(x)=x I get the correct Haar coefficients, however when I try to sum the product of the coefficient with the scaling function the function is completely off. Can somebody help me please ?

```
      function approxx(j)
      f=@(x)x;
      phi = @(x)(0 <= x < 1); %scaling function
      psi = @(x)(0 <= x < 0.5) - (0.5 <= x < 1);
      b=@(j,t,k)phi((power(2,j)*t)-k);
      a=@(x,j,k)(f(x).*b(x,j,k));
      sum=@(x)0;
      for k=0:9
      ak=integral(@(x)a(x,j,k),power(2,-j)*k,(power(2,-j)*k)+1);
      c=@(x)ak*phi((power(2,j)*x)-k);
      sum=@(x)(sum(x)+c(x));
      end
      fplot(f,[0,10]);hold on;
      fplot(sum,[0,10]);
      end
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of anonymous functions ...

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is not Python and the expression `0 <= x < 1` probably does not do what you expect. For example:

```
 >> 0 <= 10 <= 1
 ans =
        1
```